# Django count relations where conditions in foreign field is met

Tags: python, django

I am getting started on a Django project, I have four models, client, staff, booking_request, meeting_event

A client can book a lot of meetings, each meeting can involve many staffs. Each booking request is assigned to one meeting_event.

I would like to query a list of Staff objects, order by the number of client they are booked with within an meeting_event.

Currently i can figure

```
Staff.objects.annotate(num_bookings=Count('bookings_with_clients')).order_by('-num_bookings')
```

but i cannot filter the results to a specific meeting_event

Models are as below:

**Client**

**Request_booking**

- client = ForeignKey(Client)
- event = ForeignKey(MeetingEvent)
- staff = ManytoManyField(Staff)

**Staff**

**Meeting Event**

Any help would be appreciated :)

Edit:
I could return staff who are involved in a meeting, but some might occur more than once if he/ she is involved in more than a booking.

```
Staff.objects.filter(request_booking_set__event=event)
```

so i decided that this might works, and it should work fine now. Hopefully there aren't any bugs

```
Staff.objects.filter(request_booking_set__event=event).annotate(
    num_bookings=Count('code')).order_by(
    '-num_bookings')
```

Comment: Do you want to filter in the sense that you want to display the above query for a specific meeting_event. Or do you want to display a list that shows a separate record for every event a staff is involved in?

Comment: Can you post the full code for each of your 4 models?

Comment: @DisneylandSC yes just display the above query for a specific meeting_event. I think i sorted it out but would be great if you could check it.